# Is it necessary using while statement instead of if statement when using Thread wait() method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

For example if I have this code :

```
public synchronized T get() throws Exception {
        while (!condition()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
            if (!condition()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        ...
    }
```

Can I switch the while by if?

Comment: No you can't. Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--): _"interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary.

For one thing: perhaps the following happens:

1. Thread 1 starts waiting.
2. Thread 2 starts waiting.
3. Thread 3 makes the condition true and calls notifyAll.
4. Thread 1 wakes up.
5. Thread 1 makes the condition false again.
6. Thread 2 wakes up.

Now thread 2 shouldn't just assume the condition is true, because it's not!

For another thing, *spurious wakeups* are possible. This means `wait` might return for no reason at all (or no reason relevant to your program) - for instance, it might return if a debugger attaches to your program.